# Expanding text format in VI

Tags: vi, editors

The following code is taken from the superfish module for websites:

> (function($){$.fn.hoverIntent=function(f,g){var
>   cfg={sensitivity:7,interval:100,timeout:0};cfg=$.extend(cfg,g?{over:f,out:g}:f);var
>   cX,cY,pX,pY;var track=function(ev){cX=ev.pageX;cY=ev.pageY;};var
>   compare=function(ev,ob){ob.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);if((Math.abs(pX-cX)+Math.abs(pY-cY))

And once upon a time when editing this kind of file, I once accidentally hit a shortcut key that restructured the code:

```
(function($){$.fn.hoverIntent=function(f,g){
 var cfg={sensitivity:7,interval:100,timeout:0};
 cfg=$.extend(cfg,g?{over:f,out:g}:f);
 var cX,cY,pX,pY;
 var track=function(ev){cX=ev.pageX;cY=ev.pageY;};
 var compare=function(ev,ob){ob.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);
 if((Math.abs(pX-cX)+Math.abs(pY-cY))<cfg.sensitivity
  {$(ob).unbind("mousemove",track)
  etc..........
```

I want to know what that shortcut is o.0

It's like the formatting already exists but VI didn't render it?

Comment: [I realize this is an ancient question]: Could you clarify, is this actually vi or do you mean vim?

Answer (score 1):

The `vim` command to format source code is `gg=G`, it always worked for me with java or c source code; it does not work with your snippet probably because it only works with syntactically correct files.